# ARC issue with CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, core-plot, xcode4.5

I installed everything according to README file and imported all necessary libraries. Still, when implementing this method:

```
- (CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    CPTMutableTextStyle *labelText = nil;
    labelText= [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    labelText.color = [CPTColor grayColor];

    return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:@"Test" style:labelText];
}
```

I receive errors:

`ARC Semantic issue - Receiver 'CPTTextLayer' for class message is a forward declaration`
and
`ARC Semantic issue - Receiver 'CPTTextLayer' for instance message is a forward declaration`

I read in many posts, that this is the fault of missing Quartz library, though I have it imported in the project and included in the class: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.

When I return `nil` instead of this, everything works, but hey, I need those data labels to work!

Anybody knows how to make it work?

Comment: Did you try importing CPTTextLayer.h??

Comment: I did not expect **THAT**...Why didn't Xcode yell at me that it needs import?

Comment: It did, you just didn't understand the message :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `forward class error` comes when that particular class is not imported in the current class and an `@class` is declared in .h file. If `@class` is also not present, it normally gives an `unknown type error`. So in this case as mentioned in comments, it is clear that the import statement for `CPTTextLayer` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forget to import CPTTextLayer.h on your code